# Current volt master generated project listens on localhost instead of broadcast

Tags: voltrb

#### New project made with `volt new` with volt from master:

can't connect to the server from the host os (running volt in a VM)
it says:

```
Listening on localhost:3000,
```

but a new project in 0.9.6 says:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000,
```

I think it's related to thin server, I didn't look through latest commits though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that at some point thin changed its default options.  Try running with -b 0.0.0.0